# Python 3 type hinting for None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, type-hinting

```
def foo(
        hello: str='world', bar: str=None,
        another_string_or_None: str|????=None):
    pass
```

I'm trying to set a type hint in Python in a function, you can add more than one type hint with `something: str|bool='default value'`, but, what are the type hinting for `None`? :/

Comment: Why would you want to hint that a given variable should always be NoneType?

Comment: because can be a None or str

Comment: What tool are you using that reads these annotations?

Comment: What's the default state (no arguments passed)? None or str?

Comment: i'm asking about the python 3 type hinting (also known as type checks)
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have type checking. It has pep 3107 annotations, that some external tool might consider type hints. The pep specifically doesn't assign any semantics whatsoever to the annotations.

Comment: The type of `None` is `types.NoneType` in Python2, but that seems to be gone from Python3 (http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#standard-interpreter-types). So failing that, the type of `None` is `type(None)`.

Comment: If you are using an IDE that can do type-checking based on annotations, then I'd expect it to handle things like `something:(str, None)=None`, since `None` is a singleton it's quite reasonable to "identify" it to its own type from a type-checking point of view.

Comment: Doesn't cython need type hints? I think it may fail compilation in many scenarios where hints are missing...

Answer (score 154):

From your example:

```
def foo(
        hello: str='world', bar: str=None,
        another_string_or_None: str|????=None):
    ...
```

I've noticed that your use case is "something or None".

Since version 3.5, Python supports type annotations via [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).
And in your case, the recommended way of annotating is by using [`typing.Optional[something]` hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional). This has exact meaning you're looking for.

Therefore the hint for `another_string_or_None` would be:

```
import typing

def foo(
        hello: str='world', bar: str=None,
        another_string_or_None: typing.Optional[str]=None):
    ...
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for to do optional type semantics. Alternatively, to do variant type semantics, [typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) exists, or if you care about mapping of multiple signature to return types, [@typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) exists too

Comment: @solstice333 Yeah, as a sidenote to my answer: typing.Union[None, ABC] would work the same as typing.Optional[ABC]. And if you have typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, str]], you can change it to typing.Union[None, int, str].

Comment: As of Python 3.10, you can now write `str | None` instead of `typing.Optional[str]`

Answer (score 78):

Python 3.10 will support your original desired notation: `str | None`.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator)

Comment: Just a caveat to this solution in 3.10: while the pipe works for simple classes (like str), I've encountered a number of scenarios where it does not work for other classes.

Comment: @Eliot: without any details, we can't tell when it won't work for us, or if it is an error on your part.

Comment: @Oddthinking Well, **Eliot is 100% wrong.** I can guarantee that Eliot made some syntax errors. Because `Union[str, bool] == str | bool` and `Optional[str] == str | None`. There is no difference at all. Python 3.10 interprets both identically. And if your code is only meant for 3.10+, Python's core developers have said that the new `X | Y` syntax is recommended instead of `Union` or `Optional`. In both cases.

Comment: I see something similar to what @Eliot must have seen: `var: np.array | None = None` type hint gives me this error under `pytest`: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'". I am using python 3.10.13 and an up-to-date VS Code. Pylance extension does not underline it, so I guess it finds it okay, though it does underline for example tuple type hints like `var: (str, str)`.

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos: I assume your Python actually runs. Sounds like a bug in VS Code.

Comment: @Oddthinking It runs. Yes, I think too that it is a bug but it is hard to tell in which component; when pytest is started, either from terminal manually or from VS Code Testing tab, it parses the test files and imports and eventually reports the error above. VS Code is latest, 1.86.1 as are all Python related extensions.

Comment: I think Andras is probably right that it had something to do with VS Code, but to Mitch's and @Oddthinking's point, I can't say that I didn't make a syntax error. Either way, after updating VS Code, and more than three months since I encountered the error, I can't recreate it. Should I just delete the comment?

Answer (score 28):

It's just `None`!

```
>>> def nothing(nun: None) -> None:
...     return nun
... 
>>> nothing(None)
>>>
```

Or at least, it *can* be.

Since these annotations are meaningless to Python beyond being in/correct syntax, it's sort of up to the tools.

If you use [typecheck-decorator](https://github.com/prechelt/typecheck-decorator) for example, then [you'll need to](https://bugs.python.org/issue19438) use `type(None)`:

```
>>> import typecheck as tc
>>>
>>> @tc.typecheck
>>> def nothing(nun: type(None)) -> type(None):
...     return nun
... 
>>> nothing(None)
>>> nothing(0)
typecheck.framework.InputParameterError: nothing() has got an incompatible value for nun: 0
>>> nothing(False)
typecheck.framework.InputParameterError: nothing() has got an incompatible value for nun: False
```

Typecheck also allows you to somewhat more clearly "add more than one type hint with" with `tc.any()` (OR), `tc.all()` (AND), and far more besides.

Beware that `tc.none()` is a NAND-like predicate; *not* what you are looking for - with no arguments it will accept *any* type, equivalent to `tc.all()` or the more apt `tc.anything`.

Answer (score 21):

I know this question is considered answered thanks to @mbdevpl, however, I've wanted to add that `type(None)` is how you get the actual for None type, this can be useful for example in an `if statement check` like:

```
if isinstance(x_var, type(None)):
    pass
```

and since `python3.5`, you can also use do `Union` of a bunch of types with None as shown here:

```
x_var: typing.Union[str, None]
y_var: typing.Union[Dict, List, None]
```

this is equivalent to:

```
x_var: typing.Optional[str]
y_var: typing.Optional[typing.Union[Dict, List]]
```

Comment: I don't think `typing.Union[str, None]` is quite equivalent to `typing.Optional[str]` in all cases. Consider a case where you have a `TypedDict` where one of the properties is required to be `str` or `None` but cannot be omitted:

```
class MyClass(TypedDict):
    required_field: Union[str, None]
```

Comment: @Stevula yes I was going to ask this as a question, I assume if you have a `dict` with keys which are either `None` or a `str` you'd use `Union[str,None]` not `Optional[str]` since a `dict` key is not optional?

Comment: @Stevula no. It is exactly equivalent. `Optional[X]` **does not mean** "can be omitted". It means `None` or `X`

Comment: @Stevula See the [source for `Optional`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/typing.py#L523).

Comment: For information, you can now use `NotRequired` and `Required` as part of a TypedDict. By default every keys are required, or not-required when `total=False` is specified. See the PEP 655 : https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/#specification

Answer (score 6):

According to [PEP-0484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#using-none):
"When used in a *type hint*, the expression `None` is considered equivalent to `type(None)`."

I came around it when using in a type-hint signature for `@functools.singledispatch`, and annotating an argument with `None` does work for the function dispatch decorators.