# python type annotation when default argument is None

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, default-value

Maybe related:

- [Python 3 type hinting for None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202633/python-3-type-hinting-for-none)
- [In Python, how can I type hint a list with an empty default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431701/in-python-how-can-i-type-hint-a-list-with-an-empty-default-value)

```py
def other_function(x: int) -> None:
    pass

def foo(x: int = None) -> None:   # Inconsistent; how to do better ?
    if x is None:
        x = 4
    other_function(x)
```

When I arrive to the line `other_function(x)`, I'm sure that `x` is an int.

My issue is that the liner (pyright in neovim) believes that `x` is something like `Union[int, None]`, so that it does not accept to pass `x` to the `other_function`.

QUESTION : Is there a way to say "At this point, I KNOW that `x` is an `int`" ?

I've tried the solutions in the linked questions (and some variations) without success.

CLARIFICATION 1: I am not really interested in the type hint itself in the function declaration (this is the point of the linked questions). I'm intersested in making python/linter know that, after `if x is None:...`, I know that `x` is `int`.

Comment: This is a problem with your linter. Static type checkers should be able to infer that by the time you get to the `other_function` call, `x` must be an `int`. Neither PyCharm nor mypy have a problem with that code.

Comment: Also, the reason that the type checker infers the type of the `foo` parameter `x` as a union of `int` and `None` is because you used `None` as the default. You implicitly defined the type as `Union[int, None]` or `Optional[None]` or `int | None` (all equivalent). Strictly speaking you should not do that, but use an _explicit_ annotation for that.

Comment: Aside from that, you correctly used type narrowing inside of `foo` and the argument passed to `other_function` is definitively an `int`. So that warrants opening an issue with your linter/type checker.

Comment: I found my error. It was a border effect of an other portion of my actual code I did not reproduced here. My bad; I didn't checked enough my minimal example before to post here :( Anyway, thanks for your answer. I will try to stick on `int|None` which is cleared.